# Ranking and unranking combinations with replacement

Tags: combinatorics, number-systems, combinatorial-number-theory

### Problem statement:

You observe a sample of five 6-sided dice. Compute this sample's rank, then show how to unrank it.

---

### General Overview

The number of combinations with replacement can be calculated as $\frac{(n + r - 1)!}{r!(n - 1)!}$, where $n$ is the number of objects and $r$ is the number of outcomes for each object.

Substituting $n=5$ (dice) and $r=6$ (sides per dice) tells us there are $252$ outcomes in our dice problem.

**Definitions** (from [Lucia Moura's slides on Combinatorial Generation](https://www.site.uottawa.ca/%7Elucia/courses/5165-09/GenCombObj.pdf#page=4))

- Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a finite set and $N = |\mathcal{S}|$
- A *rank* function is a bijection:

$$
\textit{Rank}: \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \{0, 1, ..., N - 1\}
$$

- And the *unrank* function is the opposite bijection:

$$
\textit{Unrank}: \{0, 1, ..., N - 1\} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}
$$

For example:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1) &\rightarrow 0 \\
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2) &\rightarrow 1 \\
... \\
(2, 2, 4, 6, 6) &\rightarrow 156 \\
... \\
(5, 6, 6, 6, 6) &\rightarrow 250 \\
(6, 6, 6, 6, 6) &\rightarrow 251 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

---

### Reading + What I've tried

I was reading the Wikipedia page on [Combinatorial Number Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) and the slides above, but all the examples for ranking and unranking seem to be based on combinations **without** replacement.

For small cases (such as the one in the problem statement) it's easy to enumerate, here's an example with Python I used to construct the example above. Enumeration gets problematic for large $n$ and $r$ though, e.g. if we play with 50 dice then $|\mathcal{S}| = 3,478,761$.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

for i, sample in enumerate(combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 7), 5)):
  print(i, sample)
```

There might be a simple solution if the samples are interpreted in a different base, then adding corresponding positions. If we subtract 1 from all entries, then the ranking problem looks like this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0) &\rightarrow 0 \\
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1) &\rightarrow 1 \\
(0, 0, 0, 0, 2) &\rightarrow 2 \\
... \\
(1, 1, 3, 5, 5) &\rightarrow 156 \\
... \\
(4, 5, 5, 5, 5) &\rightarrow 250 \\
(5, 5, 5, 5, 5) &\rightarrow 251 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

... but I haven't found a general solution yet.

Comment: Hint: apply the stars and bars bijection which told you there are $\binom{n+r-1}{n}$ outcomes to begin with, and use it to transform the problem into one of ranking $n$-element subsets of $[n+r-1]$.